# Is there a simple command to install the hybrid app built by ember-cli-cordova on the device?

Tags: cordova, ember.js, ember-cli

Testing a hybrid app built by ionic on Android device is very ease and fast.
Simply plug the device in, and run

> ionic run android

then the app can be installed on the device and you can test the app on the device.

Is there a simple command to install the hybrid app built by ember-cli-cordova on a Android device?

I use windows 10 and surface pro 3.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the cordova cli like `cordova run android` in this case?

Comment: Thank your answer. 
I'll learn about ‘cordova run android’. 
I tried to use **ember cordova:build --platform=android**, it worked.

Comment: I think **ember cordova:build --platform=android** runs **cordova run android** behind.

Comment: Yep sounds reasonable... Glad you solved it!

Comment: I built an apk and installed it to my android phone by following the 'Getting started', the apk works, but it opens a browser while starting up, that is not what I expected.

How can I prevent the browser from opening when the app starts?